# VENV : Accessing system packages?

Tags: python, package, virtualenv

I want to be able to access a module installed system-wide after the venv was created.
You can see that I can access bcrypt when outside VENV w/o problem, but not inside it
(btw. installation of bcrypt inside VENV fails)

```
# apt-get install python-bcrypt

$ python -c 'import bcrypt'

$ . venv/bin/activate

(venv) $ virtualenv env --system-site-packages
New python executable in env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.

(venv) $ python -c 'import bcrypt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bcrypt
```

Comment: `virtualenv env --system-site-packages` creates a new virtual environment named `env`.  You would need to `. env/bin/activate`.

Comment: ooo i see.. thanks... venv instead env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct cmd is (venv vs env) :

```
(venv)$ virtualenv venv --system-site-packages
```